# System.log and exact URL of page caused that record

Tags: magento-1.7, logging, system.log

My System.log if full of Notices..

```
2016-03-11T08:23:39+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 0  in /var/../app/code/local/Magerevol/Brands/Block/Prodpage.php on line 29
```

I know what cause this notice, I know how to fix it and it's good that those notices are written in System.log.

The cause  that this notice appear is that I forgot to add an image in some places on product pages...

lirics...
The question is: How can I find the exact frontpage product url which caused this notice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `app/code/local/Magerevol/Brands/Prodpage.php` before line 29 you can do the following, I assume it's an array problem and line 29 contains some code like this:

```
$array[0]
```

To find out the product that's causing problem you can do:

```
if (array_key_exists(0,$array))
{
    // Do what's your code is supposed to do
}
else
{
    Mage::log("This product is missing something:".Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. For some reason your solution did not bring up the Product ID so I changed the `Mage::registry('current_product')->getProductId())` with `Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()` and that did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the file mentioned in the log - `/app/code/local/Magerevol/Brands/Block/Prodpage.php on line 29`

Here you can add your own logging, the line should be throwing some sort of exception, wherever it fails, add the following:

`$logger = Mage::getModel('core/log_adapter', 'my.log');
$logger->log(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());`

Now, next time the error occurs you will get the current URL logged in your new log file (var/log/my.log)

Comment: Your code helped me to get the url but the accual soltion was provided by @digital-pianism - Your code logs every url that was visited no matter if it trigger a notice or not.

Comment: Glad i could be of some sort of help, i was hoping the code was catching an exception, which you could then insert my code into, in this case, it would only log the url when the exception was caught. I have up-voted @digital-painism's answer.